# Why not clickable, but execute_script make sense. Python, Selenium, JS in href

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler

In Python, using Selenium, I tried to get some info about NAE members by crawler automatically. So I start from this [page](https://www.nae.edu/MembersSection/MemberDirectory.aspx?id=20412).

I located the element of next page by xpath `"//*[@title=\"Next Page\" and @class=\"next_page\"]"`, which I am sure is correct.

Then I found out that I can't do 'click' on this element, which means I can't get the next page.

Right now I have figured out that it makes sense to use:

```
element.execute_script
```

to execute javascript in href of the element, and get the next page.

So, my question is, why I get a not clickable exception, and why I can do execute_script this way?

Anyway, a lot of thanks for whoever read this question, and I am much appreciated all your comments.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Andersson , I missed that post, it's true a same story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use explicit wait for that:

`element = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".next_page")))`

2. Before clicking on the Next Page scroll to this element:

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)`

3. Then click on this button:

`element.click()`

Hope it helps you!